# Make a div either size of screen or contents (whichever is bigger)

Tags: html, css

I have a basic page, which has a header and a content with, let's say, a register from in it:

```
<div>
    <nav>
       // header
    </nav>
    <div class="container-index">
        // form
    <div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is I want the div surrounding the form to have a background image which aligns to the bottom of the page, so I use CSS like so:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container-index {
  background: url('../images/example.jpg') #e74a39;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.contaier-index.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

But this doesn't work when the viewport gets smaller than the contents, instead the background image ends halfway through the form, so I made this:

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function(e){
    var docH = parseInt($(document).height()),
        viewPortH = parseInt($(window).height());

    if (docH > viewPortH) {

        $('.container-index').removeClass('full-height');
    } else {
        $('.container-index').addClass('full-height');
    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Which is a rather terrible way of doing it.

Is there a way of doing this in CSS?

Comment: use width as 100vw

Comment: @Vishwa doesn't seem to work

Comment: if you can use bootstrap, try using img-responsive css class

Comment: @Vishwa I use bootstrap and that would not cause the div to fill the space, also this is a background image, so that can't be used

Comment: Your question is fairly ambiguous. ("But this doesn't work when the viewport gets smaller than the contents, instead the background image ends halfway through the form"); does this mean you want the image to follow the *height* rather than the width of the page?

Comment: @Martin the JS is quite self explanatory, that shows that I actually follow the height of the viewport, the issue comes with scrolling content, it works if the content never scrolls but if, on smaller screens (mobiles) it scrolls then the CSS never works right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found no reasonable CSS answer, as such the only solution was to remain with JS for this.

Comment: It looks like all you need is `background-size:cover;`.

Comment: @Martin no, check other answers

Comment: You hadn't explaind how or why background-size:cover failed. I am unclear as to why you want content to exceed the size of the viewport; unless you're trying to zoom/scale the content in which case there *will* be a CSS solution.

Comment: @Martin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570645/make-a-div-either-size-of-screen-or-contents-whichever-is-bigger/56833810?noredirect=1#comment97840960_55570714

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with few **CSS** changes and remove **jQuery** script. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476820865390-c52aeebb9891?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80') #e74a39;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container-index {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: calc(100vh - 18px);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <nav>
       // header
    </nav>
    <div class="container-index">
        // form
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure how that would make the div fill the space, but it doesn't

Comment: @Sammaye sorry for the misunderstanding. i just update the above code snippet. Thanks

Comment: That satill makes the div the size of the screen, minus 18px, it is what I have right now that doesn't work without js

Comment: That is the code, enough to produce the problem, it's really quite simple

Comment: If you want to surround background image from top to bottom you have to apply `background-image` on `body` not on `contaier-index` div.

Comment: just tried that too but the body only fills the content, unless you use the exact same method above, so you get same results whether on body or on div

Comment: Still dosn't work, the body still takes the height of the container-index on smaller screens which means it is only the size of one viewport

Comment: Can you deploy your complete code on any server or fiddle? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the various available properties background-size: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp. Mostly, background-size: cover should solve your issue.

Comment: Then it could be the problem with the aspect ratio of the image used. You could probably change the image and check.

Comment: No, it is a problem that the div fits the screen and not the content, so I added JS to fix that but the JS is a hack, read the question